# PyVRML97 needs an older version of PyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyopengl, vrml

So I set up a virtualenv, with system-site-packages on, called `vrmlmol`. Inside the `vrmlmol` env I installed `yolk` with `pip`.
Here is the output-

```
(vrmlmol)debanjan@thinkpad:~/vrmlmol$ yolk -V PyOpenGL
PyOpenGL 3.1.0b1
PyOpenGL 3.0.2
PyOpenGL 3.0.1
(vrmlmol)debanjan@thinkpad:~/vrmlmol$ yolk -V PyVRML97
PyVRML97 2.3.0a4
```

As you see the 2.x versions of PyOpenGL do not exist in PyPI. when I try to install PyOpenGL and PyVRML I get the following dependency failure:

```
(vrmlmol)debanjan@thinkpad:~/vrmlmol$ pip install -I PyOpenGL PyVRML97 
Downloading/unpacking PyOpenGL
  Downloading PyOpenGL-3.0.2.tar.gz (891kB): 891kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PyOpenGL

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.odt' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.odp' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.cvsignore' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.diff' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/*.h'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/*.xml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/*.zip'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/*.pdf'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/*.zip'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/*.txt'
    warning: no files found matching 'src/win32deps.py'
    warning: no files found matching 'src/toglinstall/get_togl.py'
    warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'OpenGL_accelerate'
Downloading/unpacking PyVRML97
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyVRML97 (from versions: 2.2.0a4, 2.2.0a5, 2.2.0a5, 2.2.0a6, 2.2.0a6, 2.2.0a7, 2.2.0a7, 2.2.0a8, 2.2.0a8, 2.3.0a1, 2.3.0a1, 2.3.0a2, 2.3.0a2, 2.3.0a3, 2.3.0a3, 2.3.0a4, 2.3.0a4)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for PyVRML97
Storing complete log in /home/debanjan/.pip/pip.log
```

Since these packages aren't present I don't see any option of using pip to install a newer PyVRML or an older PyOpenGL. Any help there? I am trying to make it easy for some colleagues to get started on their own setups .. so pip would be nice to have for them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a side-effect of the recent changes to PIP that disallow installation of alpha/beta release by default.  The last "final" release of PyVRML97 is so old that it depended on PyOpenGL 2.x (which is long since obsolete, and no longer retrievable from SourceForge via automated tools).

Unfortunately I've been remiss in getting final releases of PyVRML97 and OpenGLContext out, as I often just treat them as my personal test environment for PyOpenGL.  Until I get around to fixing that you'll need to explicitly specify the alpha releases.

To get past the particular issue, you will need to explicitly specify the PyVRML97 release:

```
$ pip install "PyVRML97==2.3.0a4"
```

To install a full, working PyVRML97/OpenGLContext environment with the currently-most-recently-released versions of all of the packages on Python 2.7 (on Linux), your command line would look like this:

```
$ virtualenv oglc-env
$ source oglc-env/bin/activate
(oglc-env)$ pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate "PyVRML97==2.3.0a4" simpleparse numpy "OpenGLContext==2.2.0a3" pydispatcher pillow
```

You may find that pillow will require extra dependencies installed at the system level to get it installed (I already have those on my machine). I've just tested the install process on a Kubuntu 13.10 machine and run an OpenGLContext demo script with the resulting virtualenv.